# Is it possible to use the same Android package name for production and development environments in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I have two Firebase projects, one for development and the other is for production.

I am currently setting up the development Firebase project to be used for our iOS/Android app developers. I already added an iOS dev application in Firebase with the same Bundle ID in both production and development projects. Now I tried to do add the Android dev app and I'm getting an error:

`An unexpected error has occurred. [Reason: Requested entity already exists]`

Is there a way around this, or do I have to use a different Android package name for the development project?

Comment: why don't you create two projects dev & production on firebase and have the configuration in your iOS, Android project to point to one of them as per current selected config?

Comment: Creating separate projects is indeed the recommended practice Junaid, so it sounds like the start of a great answer. :)

Comment: Yes, I have two projects, one for dev and one for production. The problem is that I cannot initialize the android app in Firebase for the dev project because the bundle ID is the same

Comment: Did you find a way around this?

Comment: @AXE sorry for being this guy but I don't remember at all what I did and the project went bankrupt so I haven't touched for a while... But I think it was some stupid configuration mistake by me. I can PM you the config if that helps. Please report back here if you solve it and good luck!

Comment: @Reksa Thanks! For the record - I managed to achieve it through Firebase's CLI (flutterfire configure). So, it looks like a bug in Firebase's console.